# Error: Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I recently changed configurations on my web server and moved my MySQL databases to a remote server. Upon making the changes, I removed MySQL from my web server just to make it as minimal as possible. My WordPress site was working perfect with the remote SQL until I removed it on the local server. Then I got the error:

> Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress

I'm curious as to why WordPress forces you to have it installed even while using a remote connection? Is there a way to get around this?

Worst case scenario I guess I'll reinstall MySQL.

Comment: You still need the PHP "mysql" library to access the database, regardless of where it is hosted. Do a `phpinfo();` in a script running in your web root, and see if you have this module available.

Comment: PHP needs an extension with that it can communicate with the server .

Comment: Not only a duplicate of [Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450990/your-php-installation-appears-to-be-missing-the-mysql-extension-which-is-require), but also off-topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

its not mySQL that is the issue you need to enable the mySQL extensions required by Wordpress in the php.ini file or install them if they don't exist.

When you removed MySQL it probably removed or diabled the extensions for it in PHP, atleast that is what it sounds like. You should be able to just install or enable the extensions back in without reinstalling all of mySQL

Comment: Thank you!! Running `apt-get install php5-mysql` solved my problem! I can't believe I overlooked that word "MySQL extension". D'oh!

Comment: happens to the best of us